# Detecting different patterns in a grayscale image

Tags: python

I have a grayscale image with various patterns. How can I contour around the specific pattern I need with Python, even if the sizes of the patterns vary?

[Original Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19IBd.jpg)

[Original Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiJGN.jpg)

[Expected results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZNj8.jpg)

I have tried to contour around the image but the result was not at the area I want.

[Contour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SzFo.jpg)

Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow


# Load and preprocess the image
image_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/SC200C_2533.tif'  # Update with your image path
image = cv2.imread(image_path, 0)  # Load the image as grayscale
image = cv2.medianBlur(image, 5)  # Apply median blur to reduce noise

# Apply image thresholding to separate the heartwood
_, thresholded = cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# Find contours in the thresholded image
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresholded, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Identify the largest contour (assuming it represents the heartwood)
largest_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

# Draw the contour on the original image
image_with_contour = cv2.drawContours(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR), [largest_contour], -1, (0, 0, 255), 2)

# Display the results
cv2_imshow(image_with_contour)
```

Comment: Welcome ! Where is your code?

Comment: I add my code already.